# firebase deploy Hangs in Terminal

Tags: macos, firebase, terminal, macos-sierra, firebase-tools

I am trying to upload a project to Firebase hosting.  I recently reinstalled macOS Sierra, so have fresh installs of Node and firebase-tools.

However, I get the following error when running `firebase deploy --debug`

```
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.043Z] --------------------------------------------
--------------------------
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.046Z] Command:       
/usr/local/bin/node/usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --debug
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.047Z] CLI Version:   3.9.2
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.047Z] Platform:      darwin
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.047Z] Node Version:  v8.3.0
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.048Z] Time:          Thu Aug 10 2017 16:54:40 GMT-
0500 (CDT)
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.048Z] --------------------------------------------
--------------------------

[2017-08-10T21:54:40.058Z] > command requires scope:["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform”][2017-08-10T21:54:40.059Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.061Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/dornfeld-design  
 Thu Aug 10 2017 16:54:40 GMT-0500 (CDT)
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.471Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Thu, 10 Aug 2017 21:54:40 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=121, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store
[2017-08-10T21:54:40.472Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/name-of-project/tokens  
 Thu Aug 10 2017 16:54:40 GMT-0500 (CDT)
[2017-08-10T21:54:41.061Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Thu, 10 Aug 2017 21:54:40 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=429, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store
```

Whats the best way to proceed forward?  I have tried reinstalling `firebase-tools` with 3 different versions of Node.

Additional comments:

1. had to install `firebase-tools` with `--unsafe-perm` command to get it to install.
2. `firebase init` only created `.firebaserc` file and a `firebase.json` file with `{}`
3. Manually created `firebase.json` file with proper public folder, etc.

Comment: did you tried to `firebase login`

Comment: Yes, I logged out and logged back in again after each install attempt.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or corporate firewall?

Comment: No, tried again using Yarn instead of Node and process is mostly working.  Can successfully deploy sites now.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps taken to correct problem

1. Uninstall Node `cd /usr/local/lib`
   `sudo rm -rf node_modules`
2. Install Homebrew `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
3. Install Yarn `brew install yarn`
4. Install Firebase CLI `yarn add firebase-tools`
5. Go to project folder, `firebase login`, `firebase init`
   a.  `init` creates `.firebaserc` file correctly
   b.  `firebase.json` still blank, i.e. `{}`
6. Create `firebase.json` manually:

   ```
   {
     "hosting": {
       "public": "build/unbundled",
       "ignore": [
         "firebase.json",
         "**/.*",
         "**/node_modules/**"
       ],
       "rewrites": [{
       "source": "**",
       "destination": "/index.html"
       }]
     }
   }
   ```
7. `firebase deploy` now works properly.

Comment: Had to install ```polymer-cli``` with Node instead of Yarn to get it working properly.